# Can't get extension attribute in a plugin

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4.2, extension-attributes

I am trying to create a module that uploads Category image (as Category extension attribute) via REST API. The problem is that I can't even fetch extension attributes in afterSave method of my Plugin with the lines of code below:

```
$extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->categoryExtensionFactory->create();
```

Though, obviously, extension attribute is set in my API request to
https://{{magento2_root}}/rest/async/bulk/V1/categories

```
[
    {
        "category": {
            "parent_id": 229,
            "name": "Мобільний телефон Nokia 214100",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 4,
            "include_in_menu": true,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "category_id": 456,
                "api_uploaded_image": "OnsL"
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "nokia_62100.jpg"
                },
                 {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "Good Nokia 62100"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "parent_id": 229,
            "name": "Мобільний телефон Nokia 215100",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 4,
            "include_in_menu": true,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "category_id": 457,
                "api_uploaded_image": "OnsL"
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "nokia_62100.jpg"
                },
                 {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "Good Nokia 62100"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The server gets "extension_attributes" "api_uploaded_image" and "category_id" with empty values (detailed status of bulk action with https://{{magento2_root}}/rest/V1/bulk/d6c6c3d0-5efc-4354-b52a-4dd782592515/detailed-status):

```
{
    "operations_list": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "bulk_uuid": "0fb26252-3e8b-430d-a6d8-d4d791e5c5ce",
            "topic_name": "async.magento.catalog.api.categoryrepositoryinterface.save.post",
            "serialized_data": null,
            "result_serialized_data":"{\"id\":457,\"parent_id\":229,\"name\":\"\М\о\б\і\л\ь\н\и\й \т\е\л\е\ф\о\н Nokia 214100\",\"is_active\":true,\"position\":1,\"level\":4,\"children\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2022-09-24 17:20:40\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-09-24 17:20:40\",\"path\":\"1\\/2\\/161\\/229\\/457\",\"available_sort_by\":[],\"include_in_menu\":true,\"extension_attributes\":{\"api_uploaded_image\":\"\",\"category_id\":0},\"custom_attributes\":[{\"attribute_code\":\"description\",\"value\":\"Good Nokia 62100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"image\",\"value\":\"nokia_62100.jpg\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"is_anchor\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"path\",\"value\":\"1\\/2\\/161\\/229\\/457\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"children_count\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"url_key\",\"value\":\"mobil-nij-telefon-nokia-214100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"url_path\",\"value\":\"telefoni1\\/nedorogi-mobil-ni-telefoni\\/mobil-nij-telefon-nokia-214100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"use_name_in_product_search\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"is_virtual_category\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"virtual_rule\",\"value\":{\"condition\":{\"condition_type\":\"Smile\\\\ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory\\\\Model\\\\Rule\\\\Condition\\\\Combine\",\"aggregator_type\":\"all\",\"operator\":null,\"value\":true}}},{\"attribute_code\":\"use_store_positions\",\"value\":\"0\"}]}",
            "status": 1,
            "result_message": "Service execution success Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\CategoryRepository\\Interceptor::save",
            "error_code": null
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "bulk_uuid": "0fb26252-3e8b-430d-a6d8-d4d791e5c5ce",
            "topic_name": "async.magento.catalog.api.categoryrepositoryinterface.save.post",
            "serialized_data": null,
            "result_serialized_data":"{\"id\":458,\"parent_id\":229,\"name\":\"\М\о\б\і\л\ь\н\и\й \т\е\л\е\ф\о\н Nokia 215100\",\"is_active\":true,\"position\":1,\"level\":4,\"children\":\"\",\"created_at\":\"2022-09-24 17:20:41\",\"updated_at\":\"2022-09-24 17:20:41\",\"path\":\"1\\/2\\/161\\/229\\/458\",\"available_sort_by\":[],\"include_in_menu\":true,\"extension_attributes\":{\"api_uploaded_image\":\"\",\"category_id\":0},\"custom_attributes\":[{\"attribute_code\":\"description\",\"value\":\"Good Nokia 62100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"image\",\"value\":\"nokia_62100.jpg\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"is_anchor\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"path\",\"value\":\"1\\/2\\/161\\/229\\/458\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"children_count\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"url_key\",\"value\":\"mobil-nij-telefon-nokia-215100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"url_path\",\"value\":\"telefoni1\\/nedorogi-mobil-ni-telefoni\\/mobil-nij-telefon-nokia-215100\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"use_name_in_product_search\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"is_virtual_category\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"attribute_code\":\"virtual_rule\",\"value\":{\"condition\":{\"condition_type\":\"Smile\\\\ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory\\\\Model\\\\Rule\\\\Condition\\\\Combine\",\"aggregator_type\":\"all\",\"operator\":null,\"value\":true}}},{\"attribute_code\":\"use_store_positions\",\"value\":\"0\"}]}",
            "status": 1,
            "result_message": "Service execution success Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\CategoryRepository\\Interceptor::save",
            "error_code": null
        }
    ],
    "user_type": 2,
    "bulk_id": "0fb26252-3e8b-430d-a6d8-d4d791e5c5ce",
    "description": "Topic async.magento.catalog.api.categoryrepositoryinterface.save.post",
    "start_time": "2022-09-24 17:20:40",
    "user_id": 1,
    "operation_count": 2
}
```

**1. db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sl_category_image_via_api_attribute" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Category Images Sent Via API Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="category_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" comment="Category ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="api_uploaded_image" nullable="false" comment="Base64 Encoded Images"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Create Time"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" comment="Update Time"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SL_CTGRY_IMG_VIA_API_ATTR_CATEGORY_ID_CATALOG_CTGRY_ENTT_ENTT_ID"
                    table="sl_category_image_via_api_attribute" column="category_id" referenceTable="catalog_category_entity"
                    referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

In a case I set **nullable="true"** for **name="api_uploaded_image"** attribute in db_schema.xml:

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="api_uploaded_image" nullable="true" comment="Base64 Encoded Images"/>
```

then I can save my custom entity in a custom table with "api_uploaded_image" column and NULL value:

How can I retrive category extension attribute in a Plugin (afterSave method) and then save it to my custom table?

I will be appreciate for your help.
Thanks in advance.

**2. The full code of Plugin**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Sl\CategoryImageApiUpload\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryExtensionFactory;
use Sl\CategoryImageApiUpload\Api\ManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategorySearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Sl\CategoryImageApiUpload\Model\AttributesFactory;
use Sl\CategoryImageApiUpload\Model\AttributesResource;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CategoryRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    /**
     * @var ManagementInterface
     */
    private ManagementInterface $management;

    /**
     * @var AttributesFactory
     */
    private AttributesFactory $attributesFactory;
    /**
     * @var AttributesResource
     */
    private AttributesResource $attributesResource;
    /**
     * @var CategoryExtensionFactory
     */
    private CategoryExtensionFactory $categoryExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * CategoryRepositoryPlugin constructor.
     * @param AttributesFactory $attributesFactory
     * @param AttributesResource $attributesResource
     * @param ManagementInterface $management
     * @param CategoryExtensionFactory $categoryExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        AttributesFactory $attributesFactory,
        AttributesResource $attributesResource,
        CategoryExtensionFactory $categoryExtensionFactory,
        ManagementInterface $management,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->attributesFactory = $attributesFactory;
        $this->attributesResource = $attributesResource;
        $this->categoryExtensionFactory = $categoryExtensionFactory;
        $this->management = $management;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CategorySearchResultsInterface $categorySearchResult
     * @return CategorySearchResultsInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CategorySearchResultsInterface $categorySearchResult
    ): CategorySearchResultsInterface {
        foreach ($categorySearchResult->getItems() as $category) {
            $this->afterGet($subject, $category);
        }
        return $categorySearchResult;
    }

    /**
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CategoryInterface $category
     * @return CategoryInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CategoryInterface $category
    ): CategoryInterface {
        $categoryAttribute = $this->management->getByCategoryId((int) $category->getId());

        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setCategoryId($categoryAttribute->getCategoryId());
        $extensionAttributes->setApiUploadedImage($categoryAttribute->getApiUploadedImage());

        $category->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $category;
    }

    /**
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CategoryInterface $category
     * @return CategoryInterface
     */
    public function afterSave(
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CategoryInterface $category
    ): CategoryInterface {
//        $categoryAttribute = $this->management->getByCategoryId((int) $category->getId());
//        $categoryCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getAttributesCollection();

        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->categoryExtensionFactory->create();
        if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage() !==null) {
//            $extensionAttributes->setApiUploadedImage($extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage());
            $attributesEntity = $this->attributesFactory->create();
            $attributesEntity->setCategoryId($category->getId());
            $attributesEntity->setApiUploadedImage($extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage());
//            $this->logger->debug('valuer=' .serialize($attributesEntity));
            $this->management->save($attributesEntity);
//            $this->attributesRepository->save($attributesEntity);
//            $this->$subject->save();
        }
//        $extensionAttributes->setCategoryId($categoryAttribute->getCategoryId());
//        $extensionAttributes->setApiUploadedImage($categoryAttribute->getApiUploadedImage());

//        $category->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In this case aroundSave plugin should be used. 'extension_attributes' are populated with values before CategoryRepository::save method. Then after CategoryRepository::save method 'extension_attributes' are extracted and saved to a custom table.

```
/**
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CategoryInterface $category
     * @return CategoryInterface
     */
    public function aroundSave(
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        CategoryInterface $category
    ): CategoryInterface {
//        $categoryAttribute = $this->management->getByCategoryId((int) $category->getId());
//        $categoryCollection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getAttributesCollection();

        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes()/* ?: $this->categoryExtensionInterfaceFactory->create()*/;
/*        if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage() !==null) {*/
//            $extensionAttributes->setApiUploadedImage($extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage());

        $category->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        $result = $proceed($category);

        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes();

            $attributesEntity = $this->attributesFactory->create();
            $attributesEntity->setCategoryId((int) $category->getId());
            $attributesEntity->setApiUploadedImage($extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage());

            $this->logger->debug('api_image' . $extensionAttributes->getApiUploadedImage());
            $this->management->save($attributesEntity);
//            $this->attributesRepository->save($attributesEntity);
//            $this->$subject->save();
/*        }*/
//        $extensionAttributes->setCategoryId($categoryAttribute->getCategoryId());
//        $extensionAttributes->setApiUploadedImage($categoryAttribute->getApiUploadedImage());

//        $category->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $result;
    }
```

I hope my researches will be helpful for a community.